# How to get value from HTML form in PHP and use on the same page

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I am using a PayPal button script for an eCommerce practice site. The PayPal code is an HTML form that i am echoing in PHP. I need to get the values from the form entered to use for updating a database. How can i get the amount, quantity and value form fields in PHP from the form on submit?

PayPal Form

```
$paypalButton = '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=' .$value .'>

<div class="form-group row col-xs-3 col-md-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="usr">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control"
    name="quantity" value=' .$quantity .' min="1" max="10">                 
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value=' .$paymentId .'>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=' .$itemName .'>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value=GBP>
<input type="hidden" name="UseSandbox" value="true">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value=' .$returnURL .'>
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=' .$cancelURL .'>

<div class="form-group row col-xs-12 col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" for="usr"></label>
    <input type="image" align="centre" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
</div>

</form>';
```

Comment: on submit of the form through PHP. you'll get a superglobal `$_POST[]` array of the values that you submitted in the form. You can dump these values by doing var_dump($_POST['quantity']); which will return the data from that input field from the `$_POST[]` superglobal. These values are from the name attribute from your form. So if you wanted to get any of the values, just simply call POST with the name value.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
$variable = $_POST["anotherVar"];
```

Example:

```
$paymentID = $_POST["paymentId"];
```